# finding if a vector's all elements only appear once

Tags: clojure

I have a vector - `[1 2 3 4]`

I want to check that in the vector each element appears only once. How do I do it ? One way I can think of is to convert it into a set and then back into the vector and then compare both :) However I think there should be a simpler way ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [distinct?](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/distinct_q):

```
(apply distinct? [1 2 3 4]) ;=> true
(apply distinct? [1 2 3 4 4]) ;=> false
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `distinct`:

```
(distinct [1 2 3 4 5 5]) -> [1 2 3 4 5]
```

For a check, you can do something like:

```
(= [1 2 3 4 5 5] (distinct [1 2 3 4 5 5]))
```